# SCSS styles incorrectly loaded using webpack and angular 5

Tags: angular, webpack, sass, sass-loader

I'm trying to load my scss styles during AOT compilation with Angular 5. 
Without AOT all works as expected but with AOT my css file looks almost the same as scss file.

scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "rtl";
@import "responsive";
@import "formInvalid";
$fa-font-path: "~font-awesome/fonts/";
@import "../../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

.app-content {
    margin-left: 235px;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 100px 20px;
    overflow-y: auto;

    .list-group-item {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .w-100p {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

loaded file:

```
.app-content {
    margin-left: 235px;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 100px 20px;
    overflow-y: auto; }
    .app-content .list-group-item {
    cursor: pointer; }
    .app-content .w-100p {
    width: 100%; }
```

my webpack configuration:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers.js');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require('path');

const extractSass = new ExtractTextPlugin({
    filename: "../../css/bundle.css"
});

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': './src/app/main.aot.ts'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/public/js/app'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/js/app/',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [
                'awesome-typescript-loader',
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'angular-router-loader?aot=true'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe|jpg|png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/,
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader' }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['exports-loader?module.exports.toString()', 
'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: extractSass.extract({
                    use: [{
                        loader: "css-loader"
                    }, {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }],
                    fallback: "style-loader"
                })

            }
        ],
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            sourceMap: false
        }),
        extractSass
    ]};
```

I am importing component styles like this:

```
styleUrls: ['./signin.component.scss'],
```

And global scss file wit other dependecies imported like this:

```
import "../styles/app.scss";
```

in my app.component.ts file

The problem occures also in global style and in component styles.
I have tried all possible webpack configurations with and without extract-text-plugin but nothing works.

I am not using angular cli.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The loaded CSS file looks totally fine apart from being not formatted for sure, but if you put the contents of your loaded file into your IDE and format it you will see that the CSS is actually the absolut correct representation of what you wrote in your SCSS, simply being transpiled to CSS.